# varnish - regexp to edit x-forward-for header inbound / outbound

Tags: regex, header, varnish

I am curious if anyone knows, is it possible to build a varnish config which

- looks at inbound headers from clients
- and does regexp match, to build a certain header - that is passed on to backed web server?

Context:
-- Varnish server deployed in front of 3-(apache)-webserver pool, acting as cache and LB
-- 3rd party service DDOS proxy was dropped in front of varnish recently
-- now all inbound requests to varnish have an X-Forwarded-For: header already present, indicating what the 'real' client IP address is.
-- the back-end PHP web app running on the apache hosts - wants to see only one IP address, not a 'proper' X-F-F header which shows a comma-delimited list IP1, IP2, IP3 (for external proxy; varnish as proxy, original client IP - for example)
-- ideally what I would like to do: is get Varnish to do regexp pattern match:rebuild on the existing inbound X-F-F headers; and strip away the external DDOS proxy IP address

I had tried something like this in the 'default.vcl' file,

set req.http.X-Forwarded-For = regsub(req.http.X-Forwarded-For, "123.123.123.123"," ");

where 123.123.123.123 is the IP address of the external DDOS / proxy

but this most certainly is not working / is not the correct syntax.  I'm having trouble finding good resources online that explain regexp in varnish / or good clear examples that people use.

If anyone can provide a kick in the right direction, certainly it would be greatly appreciated.

---

Thanks for comment below - I have adjusted my config now as follows,

```
if (req.http.x-forwarded-for) {
set    req.http.X-Forwarded-For = 
regsub(req.http.X-Forwarded-For, "\, 123\.123\.123\.123","");
           } else {
               set req.http.X-Forwarded-For = client.ip;
           }
```

and now I find in my apache logs, for example,

`client.ip.real.here, 123.123.123.123 - - [22/Dec/2013:07:45:17 -0800] "GET /PATH/TO/STUFF" "Mozilla/5.0.... like Gecko"`

which suggests to me the regexp is not actually doing what I thought I wanted.  Is there any way to 'test' varnish interactively, ie, feed a given VCL rule set some defined input, and then get varnish to feed out specific output; kind of a 'dry run' processing as a way to facilitate debug ?

Thanks!

Comment: Apart from the fact that dots must be escaped (`"123\.123\.123\.123"`) the regex looks fine and should at least do *something*.

Comment: Unfortunately there is nothing like dry run in Varnish, nevertheless a varnishlog trace will be usefull in this case (to see received headers and headers sent to backend)